# neo4j : transaction commit failure from a runnable jar file?

Tags: neo4j

Transaction commit failure from a runnable jar.
Commit is not happening even for 10 nodes. 
Wonder what environment values are missing?
It runs well from Eclipse.
I tried to set the maximum files that could be opened as well. But non success.

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:100)
                at graphdb.service.CypherCommand.BuildNodes(CypherCommand.java:168)
                at importdb.service.BatchNodeCreator.BeginSingleThread(BatchNodeCreator.java:88)
                at importdb.service.FlowController.Execute(FlowController.java:59)
                at main.route.NeoMain.main(NeoMain.java:41)
            Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Could not apply the transaction to the store after written to log
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.applyToStore(TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.java:82)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.commit(TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.java:51)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.commit(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:470)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.close(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:386)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:76)
                ... 4 more
            Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'BlockTreeOrds' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene50]
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.LabelUpdateWork.apply(LabelUpdateWork.java:62)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.LabelUpdateWork.apply(LabelUpdateWork.java:33)
                at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.doSynchronizedWork(WorkSync.java:121)
                at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.apply(WorkSync.java:90)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.close(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:105)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.BatchTransactionApplierFacade.close(BatchTransactionApplierFacade.java:70)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:344)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.applyToStore(TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.java:78)
                ... 8 more
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'BlockTreeOrds' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene50]
                at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:114)
                at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
                at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsReader.<init>(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:258)
                at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat.fieldsProducer(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:341)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:104)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReadOnlyClone(ReadersAndUpdates.java:197)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:99)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:435)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:286)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:261)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:251)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:137)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:154)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.partition.IndexPartition.maybeRefreshBlocking(IndexPartition.java:87)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.AbstractLuceneIndex.maybeRefreshPartition(AbstractLuceneIndex.java:334)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
                at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
                at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.AbstractLuceneIndex.maybeRefreshBlocking(AbstractLuceneIndex.java:318)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.writer.PartitionedLuceneLabelScanWriter.close(PartitionedLuceneLabelScanWriter.java:101)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.LabelUpdateWork.apply(LabelUpdateWork.java:59)
                ... 15 more
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /Users/Jaags/Documents/Neo4j/all.db
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$203(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
                at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
                at graphdb.service.GraphConnection.openGraphConnection(GraphConnection.java:27)
                at graphdb.service.GraphConnection.getGraphDBService(GraphConnection.java:31)
                at importdb.service.BatchNodeCreator.BeginSingleThread(BatchNodeCreator.java:88)
                at importdb.service.FlowController.Execute(FlowController.java:59)
                at main.route.NeoMain.main(NeoMain.java:41)
            Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@61beae3a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:503)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
                ... 10 more
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'BlockTreeOrds' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene50]
                at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:114)
                at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat.forName(PostingsFormat.java:112)
                at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsReader.<init>(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:258)
                at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat.fieldsProducer(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:341)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:104)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:65)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReader(ReadersAndUpdates.java:145)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadersAndUpdates.getReadOnlyClone(ReadersAndUpdates.java:197)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:99)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:435)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:286)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:261)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:251)
                at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:137)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:154)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:58)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:176)
                at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefreshBlocking(ReferenceManager.java:253)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.partition.IndexPartition.maybeRefreshBlocking(IndexPartition.java:87)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.AbstractLuceneIndex.maybeRefreshPartition(AbstractLuceneIndex.java:334)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
                at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
                at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
                at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.AbstractLuceneIndex.maybeRefreshBlocking(AbstractLuceneIndex.java:318)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.writer.PartitionedLuceneLabelScanWriter.close(PartitionedLuceneLabelScanWriter.java:101)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStore.rebuild(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:192)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanStore.start(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:180)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.start(RecordStorageEngine.java:422)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
                ... 18 more
```

Now I get this error after adding the below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-codecs</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene54' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [SimpleText]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:114)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:60)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Might be duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797136/neo4j-3-0-x-postingsformat-with-name-blocktreeords-does-not-exist